# securely delete entry from database with link in email

Tags: php, mysql, security

What are some safe ways of deleting an entry from the mysql database with a link in the email? I have a case where an entry can be created by a logged in user on the site. He or she will then receive an email that an entry has been created with their account but if it later appears to be an undesired entry, he or she can delete that entry with a link. Something like:

domain.com/index.php?task=delete&id=1

What are some safe methods of doing this? I could imagine adding some sort of security token to the URL, but how would I generate and validate the entire request?

Comment: avoid using actual record numbers like you did with `id=1` use some form of a hash, this will prevent the unauthenticated user from trying to delete other records, if you recall similar to what craigslist does when you publish with no craigslist account

Comment: so something like this?
`md5($id) . 'salt'`

and then reconstruct the id with the same process? (never used craigslist btw)

Comment: For a delete action I would always require an authenticated user.

Comment: @jeroen that doesn't have to be the case there are systems that handle the delete with no authentication. Anonymous systems as such exists as i mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: @DevZer0 E-mail is not a safe medium so I would not trust it with passwords, delete urls, etc. no matter who else uses it.

Answer (score 1):

I would just let your database handle this for you using `autoincrement`
You could also use uniqid for this: `md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));`
index.php:

```
for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
    echo md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)) . "\n";
}
```

output:

```
php index.php 
ba0d9aad1ff0ceadf4b25f101099b91e
b5a6db5e174b426061d3d3835a6fcaea
54be6d3a03e0590917ed20b097442e3a
6e208a61eae8cfd102d4a41decf0f64e
2cafac5402815af87e8299e5e67016bd
95e839097a566471c70fe357e5a101d2
c6908532bda6f926debdda754b02f931
aac7adf999dd4dd009f208b176ea90d0
1ed7779229e57b05adc088b375582cfb
e016a684564d5cdb89201ebab1038609
```

save this output to another column if possible or use decode function to conver to actual id

Comment: @Alex W see of he wish to use http://blog.justin.kelly.org.au/simple-base64-encodedecode-url-safe-functions/

Comment: You cannot decode md5 (except with brute-force methods...), it's a hash, not an encryption method.

Comment: @jeroen, i am not talking about md5 decode, i am talking about to use base64 function to encode and decode to manage for security purpose.

Comment: @liyakat Just so you know, base64 encoding is not much more secure than plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways I can think of are:

1. Store a random "access token" as part of the database entry.  The token should have at least 64 bits of entropy.  Include the token in the deletion link, and refuse any deletion attempts that have the wrong token.
2. Same as above, but instead of storing the token in the database, calculate it from the record ID using a [message authentication code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) (such as [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC)) and a secret key.

In either case, your links are going to look something like this:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?task=delete&id=1&token=d7a8fbb307d78094
```

One advantage of the second method, besides saving storage space, is that you can have different tokens for different actions just by including the action in the "message" you compute the MAC for.  For example, the token above might be computed for the message "`delete 1`", whereas "`edit 1`" would have a completely different MAC.

In PHP, you can use [`hash_hmac()`](http://php.net/hash_hmac) to calculate the MAC.